# Is there create snapshot and restore snapshot tasks in ssis?

Tags: ssis

I am looking for way to create database snapshot. And on error restore the database with the snapshot. Is there ssis task available for creating and restoring database snapshot?

Comment: If you can not find something built in you can create your own using C# Script Task.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you're going to be using the Execute SQL Task for snapshot creation and restore.

- [Create Database Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database-snapshot-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Revert Database Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/revert-a-database-to-a-database-snapshot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Using the EXECUTE SQL TASK :
[image]

In the SQL Statement, this will be your query :

**Create Database Snapshot :**

```
CREATE DATABASE database_snapshot_name

ON

(

NAME =logical_file_name,

FILENAME ='os_file_name'

) [ ,...n ]

AS SNAPSHOT OF source_database_name
```

**Revert Database Snapshot :**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT dbid FROM sys.databases  
    WHERE NAME = 'yourdb')  
    DROP DATABASE dbsnapshot;   
-- Reverting CurrentDB  to your DB Snapshot  
 
RESTORE DATABASE CurrentDB FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT = 'yourdb';
```

[image]